# Entity Framework - manual db change scripts

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am fairly new to EF. A C#/WPF application is deployed (in house) and I want to allow the user to apply updates which include db schema changes (SQL Server CE). The user would get a new installer, and a compatibility checker would then prompt for a SQL script to apply after which the app would be restarted with all updated. It would also be desirable, of course, to do this updating as part of the (re)install cum application update. Obviously it is essential that there is no data loss (schema changes are likely to be new columns rather than type changes).

So many references to this involve Package Manager commands and the like, that I struggle to find a straightfroward way to do this at runtime C#/WPF, on the user's machine. Yes, Migrations may be the answer, but my code-first project does not include the EF package. I could possibly remove `MigrationHistory` but then I like the compatibility checking. Is there a way to manually apply a change script and somehow update `MigrationHistory` manually so that the new schema is seen as compatible? At the moment, the db IS compatible to my eyes, but EF thinks it isn't. Perhaps the answer is to go totally manual (devise own versioning method) or totally auto, with EF Migrations. The latter is attractive, but can I apply it retrospectively?

Any help appreciated, esp in the general area of updating db schemas in live applications at runtime.

Comment: Suggesting you rather than looking for an alternative option. Take the backup of deployed one perform automatic migration. if you think manually fixing it may be Rollback to last migration and try squash it up. The reason is you have **meshed up migration history**.

Comment: EF does not support this, as it can't determine the model of the db it is supposed to be compatible to. However, there is a workaround - you can set the initializer to null and compare the schemas yourself. However, this would require your own schema scheck (probably with reflection) and some hassle on context initiation.

Comment: The solution seems to be either all-manual, or all-automatic, with the latter being more attractive, and yes, I will need to get my migration history in sync somehow (not sure just how, so far). But, I have still to find a good guide on real-life schema updating for end-user deployment.